# Setting specific color per label in chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm trying to set colors for charts made using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) library.

I need a specific color for each data label. but when data of specific labels is zero colors get confused :(.

it looks like the library drops zero-data labels and labels colored differently.

**For example, when data is:**

- **colors:** `green`, `red`, `yellow`,
- **labels:** `passed`, `failed`, `in progress`
- **data:** `0`, `5`, `80`

passed labeled data will be skipped as its value is zero, so failed labeled data gets the first color: `green`, and so on.

How can I force colors matching?

---

Current code:

html:

```html
<canvas baseChart height="150px" width="150px" [data]="graphData" [labels]="graphLabels" [colors]="graphColors"
    [options]="graphOptions" [legend]="false" [chartType]="'doughnut'">
</canvas>
```

TypeScript:

```js
this.graphData = this.data.map(r => r.cnt);
this.graphLabels = this.data.map(r => r.city);
this.graphOptions = {
    layout: {padding: 20},
    cutoutPrecentage: 90,
    legend: {display: false}
};
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var graphData = {
    labels: ['Passed', 'Failed', 'In Progress'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Data',
        data: [0, 5, 80],
        backgroundColor: [
            "green",
            "red",
            "yellow"
        ],
    }]
};
```

Or in your chart creation add the `data`

> Only if you do the `new Chart(...)`
>
> `graphData` as parameter to the `canvas` is great

```js
var chr = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: graphData,
    type: 'pie',
    options: options,
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09f1h5o8/)